# Ensure that the 'dir.root' property '/var/lib/alfresco/alf_data_dev' is pointing to the correct data

Tags: alfresco-share

We are doing the alfresco 5.1 installation in multiple servers in clone env.Except in one server ,we are seeing below error other 3 servers.To resolve this error we have done below steps but no luck.please note that below path was there in all servers.

```
1)Stop all shared servers 
2)Drop database schema and create new schema. 
3)Delete contents(contentstore & contentstore.deleted) inside /var/lib/alfresco/alf_data_dev 
4)Start all shared servers. 


07-28 07:01:30,864  ERROR [repo.admin.ConfigurationChecker] [localhost-startStop-1] CONTENT INTEGRITY ERROR: System content not found in content store.
2016-07-28 07:01:30,864  ERROR [repo.admin.ConfigurationChecker] [localhost-startStop-1] Ensure that the 'dir.root' property '/var/lib/alfresco/alf_data_dev_new' is pointing to the correct data location.
2016-07-28 07:01:30,867  ERROR [web.context.ContextLoader] [localhost-startStop-1] Context initialization failed
org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 06280002 Ensure that the 'dir.root' property '/var/lib/alfresco/alf_data_dev' is pointing to the correct data location.
                at org.alfresco.repo.admin.ConfigurationChecker.check(ConfigurationChecker.java:263)
                at org.alfresco.repo.admin.ConfigurationChecker.access$0(ConfigurationChecker.java:198)
                at org.alfresco.repo.admin.ConfigurationChecker$1$1.doWork(ConfigurationChecker.java:186)
                at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:555)
                at org.alfresco.repo.admin.ConfigurationChecker$1.execute(ConfigurationChecker.java:182)
                at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:464)
                at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:352)
```